# Removing HTML formatting when sending content to an email with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, replace

Hopefully this is quite a simple one for someone who knows Javascript a bit better than me.

I have a button that sends the contents of a div tag to an email,

The js behind it is a rather simple

```
function doMailTo(addr) {
location.href = "mailto:"+addr+"?subject=Flight Itinerary&body="+document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML;
}
```

This sends the content to the email however the html formatting is included, and the email looks really messy (below is the body content of the email):

```
<b>Sat 21 Oct - Flybe 6350 </b><b>- 0h 50m</b><br>Depart: Jersey Airport,  (JER) at 07:00<br>Arrive: Southampton Airport,  (SOU) at 07:50 <br><br>
```

when I want it to look like this:

Sat 21 Oct - Flybe 6350 - 0h 50m
Depart: Jersey Airport,  (JER) at 07:00
Arrive: Southampton Airport,  (SOU) at 07:50

I'm aware that I want to remove the

```
<b> & </b>
```

And Replace the

```
<br/>
```

with

```
\r\n
```

But I don't know how to make this work in js, I've tried many many variations of the below,

```
(replace(brRegex, "\r\n").replace(/<\/?[a-zA-Z]+\/?>/g, ''))
```

But I can't work out how to put into the above function so that it works,

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `document.getElementById('p3').textContent` (or `innerText`) instead?

Comment: I did try that, however I need the line breaks to remain so the text is over three lines, and with .textContent the text remains on one line,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the text is on three lines, you need to use [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) after getting the textContent instead of innerHTML:

- using textContent saves you from replacing unwanted items
- encodeURI is required to encode correctly the new lines chars.

```js
function doMailTo(addr) {
    location.href = "mailto:" + addr + "?subject=Flight Itinerary&body=" +
          encodeURI(document.getElementById('p3').textContent);
}

doMailTo('ooo@xxx.uu');
```

```html
<div id="p3">
    <b>Sat 21 Oct - Flybe 6350 </b><b>- 0h 50m</b><br>
    Depart: Jersey Airport, (JER) at 07:00<br>
    Arrive: Southampton Airport, (SOU) at 07:50<br><br>
</div>
```